# Rendering 2 blocks as a single element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a bunch of html output that I receive like this

```
<div>
<h4>This</h4><p>Value 9.6 m.</p>
<h4>That</h4><p>Value 9.6 m.</p>
<h4>The other</h4><p>Another 7.69 m.</p>
<h4>And yet</h4><p>Another value 4.8 m.</p>
</div>
```

and I want to have it rendered something like this

**This:** Value 9.6 m.

**That:** Value 9.6 m.

**The other:** Another 7.69 m.

**And yet:** Another value 4.8 m.

I think it probably should have been created as a definition list, but i don't control the html generation.

I can get the first **h4 p** 'block' to render correctly with the following but I can't seem to get subsequent 'blocks' to render as desired.

```
h4:after {  content: ": ";  display: inline;  white-space: nowrap;  }  h4 {  display: block; }
h4~p {  display: block; }          
h4:first-child {  display: inline;}
h4+p {  display: inline;  }
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired output?

TIA

Comment: I think it will be easier to achieve this with JS

Answer (score 1):

If  you don't need a tidy column or grid layout for these, I found Ye Olde Floats worked best:

```
// normalize the spacing and stuff between the h4 and p
h4, p {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

h4 {
    // honestly, this got the most sturdy result
    float: left;

    // add the colon and a  little space
    &:after {
        content: ": ";
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
}

// break the line after each P
p {
    &:after {
        display: block;
        clear: right;
        content: "";
    }
}
```

I also threw this into a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/code-and-pixels/pen/OJbzzWJ).

Also if you would like a more tabular or column-y version, I had some luck with flexbox and css grid.

Hope this helps, happy coding!